# how could log4j resolve variable in log4j.xml successfully?

Tags: maven, log4j, jetty

In my `maven` web project, there is a `log4j.xml` in resources folder,

```
    <appender name="App" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${merchant.log.dir}/sys.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d - %c -%-4r [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
   </appender>
```

and in the root directory there is a `application.properties`

```
ls
application.properties  pom.xml  src  target
```

in this `application.properties` file have this key value

```
merchant.log.dir=/foo/logs/merchant
```

and in pom.xml

```
        <filters>
            <filter>application.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        </resources>
```

when I started this project use `jetty`, it outputs below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foo/logs/merchant/sys.log (No such file or directory)
```

I'm very confused how `log4j.xml` could resolve `${merchant.log.dir}` successfully? Does `log4j` do this work itself? or Jetty at first read `pom.xml` than replace `${merchant.log.dir}` with `/foo/logs/merchant`

Comment: Could you post your POM? My guess is that the resources are being filtered. You should see a `<resources><resource><directory>...</directory><filtered>true</filtered></resource></resources>`.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

after commenting below part in `pom.xml`

```
<!--         <filters> -->
<!--             <filter>application.properties</filter> -->
<!--         </filters> -->
```

then starts the project, the output file is `/sys.log`. So it must be when jetty starts it replace `${merchant.log.dir}` to value of `merchant.log.dir` in `application.properties`.

BTW after modifying `pom.xml` you have to execute `maven --> Update Project` explicitly, or it will not  take effect.